# Multiple if else statements to get non-empty value from a map in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have a string to string map, and its value can be an empty string. I want to assign a non-empty value to a variable to use it somewhere. Is there a better way to write this in Scala?

```
import scala.collection.mutable
var keyvalue = mutable.Map.empty[String, String]
keyvalue += ("key1" -> "value1")

var myvalue = ""
if (keyvalue.get("key1").isDefined &&
    keyvalue("key1").length > 0) {
  myvalue = keyvalue("key1")
}
else if (keyvalue.get("key2").isDefined &&
    keyvalue("key2").length > 0) {
  myvalue = keyvalue("key2")
}
else if (keyvalue.get("key3").isDefined &&
    keyvalue("key3").length > 0) {
  myvalue = keyvalue("key3")
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please elaborate and augment your code with comments so that I can help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A more idiomatic way would be to use `filter` to check the length of the string contained in the `Option`, then `orElse` and `getOrElse` to assign to a val. A crude example:

```
def getKey(key: String): Option[String] = keyvalue.get(key).filter(_.length > 0)

val myvalue: String = getKey("key1")
    .orElse(getKey("key2"))
    .orElse(getKey("key3"))
    .getOrElse("")
```

Here's a similar way to do it with an arbitrary list of fallback keys. Using a `view` and `collectFirst`, we will only evaluate `keyvalue.get` for only as many times as we need to (or all, if there are no matches).

```
val myvalue: String = List("key1", "key2", "key3").view
    .map(keyvalue.get)
    .collectFirst { case Some(value) if(value.length > 0) => value } 
    .getOrElse("")
```

Comment: +2 for providing efficiency guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Mmm, it seems it took me too long to devise a generic solution and other answer was accepted, but here it goes:

```
     def getOrTryAgain(map: mutable.Map[String, String], keys: List[String]): Option[String] =
     {
        if(keys.isEmpty)
           None
        else
           map.get(keys.head).filter(_.length > 0).orElse(getOrTryAgain(map, keys.tail))
     }
     val myvalue2 = getOrTryAgain(keyvalue, List("key1", "key2", "key3"))
```

This one you can use to check for as many keys as you want.